# How to retrieve liker id based on ques_id?

Tags: php, sql

Here is my database:

```
id | liker | ques_id
1  | 15    | 2342
2  | 22    | 2342
3  | 22    | 2311
4  | 15    | 2389
```

What I need to get is all the liker's who have liked `ques_id`. So the result should look something like this:

```
Question 2342 has been liked by 15 and 22.
Question 2311 has been liked by 22 and so on
```

My current code produces separate row for each liker and `ques_id`:

```
$sqlq=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes");
while($rowq=mysql_fetch_array($sqlq)){
  $qid=$rowq['ques_id'];

  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes where ques_id='$qid'");
  $num=mysql_num_rows($sql);
  $cont='';

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $liker=$row['liker'];
    $cont .="$qid being liked by $liker<br>";
  }
  echo $cont;
}
```

Comment: Change your query as per my suggestion and you only have one loop to process the rows and output a string as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it should get you started:

```
$sqlq=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(ques_id) FROM likes");
$cont='';
while($rowq=mysql_fetch_array($sqlq)){
  $qid=$rowq['ques_id'];

  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes where ques_id='$qid'");
  $num=mysql_num_rows($sql);
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)
  $cont .= "$qid being liked by $liker ";

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $liker=$row['liker'];
    $cont .= " and $liker";
  }
  $cont .= ".<br>";
}
echo $cont;
```

Comment: There is a problem because code repeats same ques_id everytime it finds it in SQL...I need ques_id only to be outputed once although it is on two or more rows in DB

Comment: Okay, add this to the first query:
    " DISTINCT(ques_id) "  I added it to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need no second query to DB, it enough iterate only first result.
For example, you may collect all the likers, that match a specific ques_id in a assoc array with keys are ques_id, like this:

```
$mathces = array();
$sqlq=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes");
while($rowq=mysql_fetch_array($sqlq)){
  $qid=$rowq['ques_id'];
  $liker=$rowq['liker'];

  $matches[ $qid ][] = $liker;
}
```

Then, you may foreach `$mathces` array and build you string.

```
foreach ($matches as $qid => $likers) {
  $cont .= "$qid being liked by " . implode(' and ', $likers );
  if (count($likers) == 1)
    $cont .= ' and so on';
  echo "$cont<br>";
}
```

I didn't test my code. It need to additional validations (e.g. for `$linkers` in second loop)

Comment: what exactly? what output?

Comment: 2342 being liked by 15 and 22
2342 being liked by 15 and 222341 being liked by 15 and 22
2342 being liked by 15 and 222341 being liked by 15 and 222356 being liked by 15 and so on
2342 being liked by 15 and 222341 being liked by 15 and 222356 being liked by 15 and so on2312 being liked by 22 and so on
2342 being liked by 15 and 222341 being liked by 15 and 222356 being liked by 15 and so on2312 being liked by 22 and so on2311 being liked by 22 and so on
It outputs something like this with much longer code...it doesn't makes much sense

Comment: It is strange, but for you test data I have out:
2342 being liked by 15 and 22
2311 being liked by 22 and so on
2389 being liked by 15 and so on. Are you shure add linker with $matches[ $qid ][] = $liker; ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(liker), ques_id FROM likes GROUP BY ques_id
```

That will pull each liker grouped together for each ques_id.
You then only have to process the rows returned.

You should steer clear of the [mysql extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) as it is deprecated; use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

```
$sql = 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(liker) as likes, ques_id FROM likes GROUP BY ques_id';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    printf('Question %s is liked by %s', $row['ques_id'], $row['likes']);
}
```